# Not able to write to a file in Fedora using Perl

Tags: perl, file-io, fedora

I have my exam tomorrow and am stuck with this part of a lab experiment.

**Experiment:** Write a Perl program to keep track of the number of visitors visiting the webpage and to display this count of visitors, with proper headings.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use CGI':standard';
use CGI::Carp qw(warningsToBrowser fatalsToBrowser);
print "Content-type: text/html","\n\n";
open(FILE,'<count.txt');
$count=<FILE>+1;
close(FILE);
open(FILE,'>count.txt');
print FILE "$count";
print "This page has been viewed $count times";
close(FILE);
#print $count;
```

I have changed `count.txt`'s permissions to 755 in Fedora.

On every page load the count successfully incremented when executed on XAMPP in Windows XP (with a proper shebang line). But I couldn't execute it on Fedora. Unfortunately, in my exam, I have to execute on Fedora.

Comment: What is the error that you get? If you put an `or die` on the open file command, does it die?

Comment: but executing it with `$ perl broken_script.pl` manually should work on all platforms

Comment: I don't know patrons, If I get this experiment tomorrow, I am sure to fail...

Comment: As what user is this script running on Fedora? It is not uncommon to take write access from the server. Does the server user have write access to the file, not just you?

Comment: @amon, root.... How to check whether server has permissions?

Comment: @PhilH, I didn't get you...

Comment: Can anyone provide me with a fresh code ...?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Always use `use strict; use warnings;`! Had you done so, you would have received the following errors in your error log:

```
Global symbol "$count" requires explicit package name
```

Once you fix the missing `my`, you'll get the following errors in your error log:

```
readline() on unopened filehandle FILE
print() on unopened filehandle FILE
```

You would check why your handle isn't open by checking the error returned by `open`.

```
open(FILE,'<count.txt') or die "Can't open count.txt: $!\n";
open(FILE,'>count.txt') or die "Can't create count.txt: $!\n";
```

The first says the file doesn't exist. The second would give you a permission error if the program were to get that far. That's because you are trying to access a file named `count.txt` in the root directory (`/`). Change the cwd or use an absolute path.

---

By the way, you have a race condition. If two requests come in at the same time, you'll end up only counting one of them.

```
 |   process 1                      process 2
 |   ----------------------------   ----------------------------
 T   Read count from the file (4)
 i   Add 1 to count (5)
 m                                  Read count from the file (4)
 e                                  Add 1 to count (5)
 |                                  Save new count to file (5)
 v   Save new count to file (5)
```

You need to utilize a locking mechanism.

Comment: So much win in this answer.

Answer (score 2):

The shebang (`#!`) must be the first characters of the file.

Comment: shebang? I am just a few programs old in Perl? Could you explain please...?

Comment: @TabrezAhmed The shebang tells the system (on \*nixes like Linux) what interpreter to load for this file. The byte sequence `#!` is a *magic number*, so your file has to be encoded in ASCII or UTF-8. Common shebang lines are `#!/bin/sh` for shell scripts or `#!/usr/bin/perl` for perl. On Windows, this has no meaning, although perl will parse the switches supplied on this line.

Comment: I have supplied both the lines of code which have used on the two operating systems respectively.

Comment: Yes as you said, it is the first character.

Comment: @ikegami, I have excluded my code's first line in fedora and the second line in windows. So that is not the problem.